# Queueing theory, meaning of Beta in a Weibulldistribution

Tags: queueing-theory

I'm having some issues with a service system where customers arrive randomly, following a Poissonprocess. The lengths in time that customers spend in service are independent and Weibull distributed with the parameters α > 0 and β > 0.

We are testing two different values of β - 1 and 2 - and get two very different behaving queues. My question is how does β actually affect the behaviour of the queue and why? When β = 1 , the queue becomes a M/G/∞ queue, is this why the behaviours are different or how does it really work?

Thanks and I excuse my bad language

Comment: In the first paragraph it sounds like you are describing an M/G/1 queue with service times having a Weibull distribution, but then in the second paragraph you suggest that changing a distribution parameter would change the model structure? The beta parameter of the Weibull distribution is the shape parameter describes the behaviour in different cases https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution (where your variable beta is referred to as k).

Comment: I'm not very good at the different kinds of queues. But I'm sure we have a M/G/∞-queue when β = 2. But when β = 1, the Weibull-distribution becomes an exponential distribution, and the queue becomes a M/M/∞-queue, is that right? How does that affect the behaviour of the queue, practically speaking?